# How to implement an E-commerce solution for a jobboard?

Tags: commerce, webforms

What would be the best way of achieving this goal:

- From a jobs board (A content type called jobs)
- User picks particular job
- User is asked to complete a form including:

  - Checkboxes (for terms and conditions)
  - Document upload (CV, picture etc)
  - Other basic details (name etc)
- User then pays a fee via eCommerce caperbility
- All the information and documents are available for admin to view.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is overly broad and requests opinions. Flagged as such.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with the [Recruiter Distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/recruiter) and [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) or [Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

If you are not using the recruiter distribution you can used the [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) to created to ask

> - Checkboxes (for terms and conditions) 
> - Document upload (CV,
>   picture etc) 
> - Other basic details (name etc)

For the Terms and conditions you can used the [Site Disclaimer](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_disclaimer) module.

You need to created a role that allows them to register to the website and created a profile. After that you can add a button to Upgrade their to another role which would give the user the ability to see or do more stuff in your website.

You can follow this tutorial to learn how to upgrade a role with Ubercart. [How to Configure Drupal 7 and Ubercart to Sell User Roles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vd6Y4f4TnnU)

Comment: Would this allow it in the following stages, each on a page:
Step 1 - Select Job.
Step 2 - Complete form, upload documents & accept terms.
Step 3 - Pay online for application.
N.B. No user account signup.